# Going back to code while debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

From the createSecureConnection method in my code , i came to exception block

catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Please tell me is it possible to go back to the createSecureConnection  from the catch block ??

please see the scren shot here .

```
http://imageupload.org/?d=8E567A951
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a finally block and call it again. but should happen if it fails again?

EDIT:

the finally block is always executed, also if the first call was successful. I'm not sure if this is a good approach, but if you want to do it like this, you have to simply use boolean flag like this:

```
boolean success = false; 
try{
   ....
   urlc = createSecureConnection(urlString); 
   success = true; 
 }
 catch()
 { ... }
 finally
 { 
    if(!success) try{ createSecureConnection(urlString); }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you , Is calling  it again is compulsary ??

Comment: Thnk you very much , Please dont bother about the code as its not written by me , it was just imported , i wasking about going back to the debug point instead of calling it again .